# How data frame handle data type?

Tags: r, dataframe

I have encountered an issue that I do not understand and could not find an explanation so far. Here is an example :

```
x = matrix(data = "test", nrow = 5, ncol = 3)
typeof(x[1, 1])
> "character"

x = as.data.frame(x)
typeof(x[1, 1])
> "integer"
```

Any idea as to why `as.data.frame()` coerce data to integer type and how to prevent it from happening ?

Comment: That is perfect ! I think you should post it as an answer so I can close that thread :)

Answer (score 2, accepted):

The `matrix` can hold only a single class.  Normally, we use `matrix` for numeric elements.  Suppose if there is a single element in `matrix` that is non-numeric, it will convert the whole matrix to `character` class.

Regarding the OP's post, we have a `matrix` with `character` elements.  Coercing a `matrix` to `data.frame` (with `as.data.frame`), it will be converted to `data.frame`, but the default option (`stringsAsFactors=TRUE)` in `data.frame` for 'character' elements in each column will be to convert it to `factor` class.  When we use `typeof`, we get the `integer` representation of `factor`.

This can be avoided by using `stringsAsFactors=FALSE`

```
 x1 <- as.data.frame(x, stringsAsFactors=FALSE)
```